# Definition of tangent vector of a unit speed curve, related to curvature in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I am set out to find the curvature of a plane curve, given by the formula
$$k=\frac{\rho^2-\rho\,\rho''+2\,(\rho')^2}{\left[(\rho')^2+\rho^2\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
where the primes denotes a derivative with respect to $\theta$, and $\rho$ is the radial coordinate, function of the angle.
In my derivation I managed to get the expression in the numerator multiplied with $\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^3$ and I'm told the relationship between this and the radial coordinate plus its derivative can be found by considering that the tangent vector is unitary, but I don't understand. I thought the tangent vector was only unitary if it was parameterised by arclength. I don't think that is the case here, so I am confused. However, indeed,
$$T\cdot T=1 \iff |S'|^2\dot{\theta}^2=1 \iff\dot{\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho^2+\rho'^2}}$$
by chainrule (S being the parametrization of the curve). But I don't see how this could be the case without restricting my derivation to unit speed curves. What am I missing?

Comment: So $t$ is the arclength parameter for the curve? $T = \dfrac{dS}{dt} = \dfrac{dS/d\theta}{dt/d\theta} = S'\dot\theta$, as you suggest. When you do the chain rule corrections in your curvature computation, you should be dividing by $(dt/d\theta)^3$, which is multiplying by $\dot\theta^3$, yes. It might be helpful to use the letter $s$ for arclength, as everyone (else) does in these sorts of computations.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was using $t$ as an arbitrary parameter for the curve. Should I have used arclength?

Comment: Yes, since curvature is most directly defined as $\|dT/ds\|$ (where $s$ is arclength), you should always relate to an arclength parametrization.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see so I should always commence with that definition since it is the most direct. Thanks